# Visual Studio 2017 has incorrect Android Virtual Machines

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I've been working on an Android app (Cordova) in VS 2015 and debugging was working well.

I then installed VS 2017 and gave a Xamarin app a try. After successfully launching and debugging a few times, I decided to go back to my Cordova app. Once I opened the Cordova app in VS 2017 all of the non-browser based emulators do not work.

Even switching back to the Xamarin project doesn't work for debugging now.

Each time I attempt to debug, it either gets stuck on "deploying" in the task bar (with no error message in output), or it gets to "Launching Debug" and eventually says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I notice that the Debug virtual device options in Visual Studio do not seem to match those in AVD. I guess this might be the culprit, but I don't know how to force them to synchronize:
[image: VS Emulator List]
[image: AVD Manager List]

I'm really at a loss for what to look at, since I expected the Android emulator to "Just work" (TM)

I have already done a Repair operation on VS 2017, and the result is the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update and partial fix**
I've found that "Google Emulator - Phone" will at least launch an emulator from AVD, but it seems I can't control which one. It still seems something is not synchronized.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this, I am facing the same issue, after having VS 2015 and VS 2017 in same machine.

Comment: @Mrunal - my "solution" was to just use the "Google Emulator". It seems that in the upgrade the old 2015 VMs get stuck in the menu. I haven't figured out how to remove them, nor have I tried now that I can run the emulator :).